# ZF2 trouble with linking to database

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

First a little introduction. I am using wamp and ZF-Skeleton-Application is in:

```
www\firstApplication
```

So I went through the first tutorial application of the ZF-Website. This includes the module Album so the browser leads to it with the following path:

```
http://localhost/firstApplication/public/album
```

There I get an

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException
```

saying that the...

```
Statement could not be executed (42S02 - 1146 - Table 'blog.album' doesn't exist)
```

The tut also includes a change of the

```
config\autoload\global.php
```

with the following code in it:

```
 'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'username'       => 'root',  //edit this
     'password'       => '',  //edit this
     'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
     ),

  'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
```

After I followed the second In-depth Tutorial that was a problem because the settings are global of course so I comment it.

The module has the following structure:

```
module/
    Album/
        config/
            module.config.php
        src/
            Album/
                Controller/
                    AlbumController.php
                Form/
                    AlbumForm.php
                Model/
                    Album.php
                    AlbumTable.php
        view/
            album/
                album/
                    add.phtml
                    delete.phtml
                    edit.phtml
                    index.phtml
        autoload_classmap.php
        Module.php
```

I put the settings above in the module.config.php and it leads to the Exception with the blog Database which I have in another module called Blog (of the In-Depth tut).

So I checked the global.php and the local.php (in the same folder). There is no database-reference.

Also I checked all files in the module. The autoload_classmap.php is empty. I also tried it out to put it in there, but it is still the same error.

So I do not have a clue where to search for the database reference which leads to another module. My last idea is, that it has todo something with the following method in Module.php:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
     return array(
         'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
             __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
         ),
         'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
             'namespaces' => array(
                 __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
             ),
         ),
}
```

In the tutorial is written:
"Zend Framework 2’s ModuleManager merges all the configuration from each module’s module.config.php file and then merges in the files in config/autoload (*.global.php and then *.local.php files)."

But global.php and local.php are emtpy, there is absolutly nothing in it.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean by the "database reference which leads to another module"? What is it you think is causing your error? The error suggests that the `album` table in the database does not exist. It should have been created through following step of the tutorial: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: I edit it. In the question I copied the config from another module. Now, you can see there is now reference to "blog". Only a reference to "zf2tutorial".

Comment: Okay, understood. So which URL is giving you that error, and are you sure that URL is taking you to the right application? Also, do you have any cache related folders in your project?

Comment: 1. The URL is the one above: 

http://localhost/firstApplication/public/album

Yes I am sure the URL is taking me to the right application: http://localhost/firstApplication/public/blog and http://localhost/firstApplication/public/application are working fine.

2. The Skeleton-Application which I created with composer has the folder: data\cache with .gitignore in it.

Or maybe there are another folder? What are "cache related folders" ?

Comment: It is like I said, when I change mysql:dbname in the other module it works, so there has to be reference to this modul.config.php

Comment: So you've put both modules in the same application, but you want them to use different databases?

Comment: Yes, exactly. After the first tut I thought the big adventage is that in different configs I can link to different databases. Or is there a generally issue?